# Sorting of Arraylist by date only sorts day and not month and year?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, date-sorting

I'm attempting to SORT an ArrayList by (Type Date) MyObject.getDate()

My format is formatted by SimpleDateFormat by dd-mm-yyyy;
I'm using a custom comparator to sort my list.
I'm using Collections.sort(produuctList, new CustomComparator())

Problem my sorted list is only by dd and not dd-mm-yyyy.

Any ideas?

```
public class Product
{
    private String productName; 
    private Date boughtOn;
    private Date useBy; 
    private double boughtAt; 
    private long quantity; 
    private static DateFormat dateFormat;


    public Date getUseBy()
    {
        return useBy;
    }
    public void setUseBy(Date useBy)
    {
        this.useBy = useBy;
    }
}

public static Date rtnDate(String dateStr, int currentLineCount)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
        try
        {   
            Date date = df.parse(dateStr);
            return date;
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            productParsingErrorMessages.add("Date parse exception: " + e + "on line " + currentLineCount);
            return null;
        }

//      DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
//      Date date2 = (Date)formatter.parse(dateStr);
    }
```

> ```
> System.out.println("Product list - BEFORE sorting by UseBy");
> printInventory(produuctList);
>
> Collections.sort(produuctList, new CustomComparator());
>
> System.out.println("Product list - AFTER sorting by UseBy");
> printInventory(produuctList);
> ```

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Product>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Product o1, Product o2)
    {
        return o1.getUseBy().compareTo(o2.getUseBy());
    }
}
```

Product list - BEFORE sorting by UseBy

Product name: sugar  UseBy : 12-12-2012
Product name: sugar  UseBy : 01-10-2012
Product name: sugar  UseBy : 16-04-2012
Product name: sugar  UseBy : 30-01-2012
Product name: sugar  UseBy : 25-04-2012
Product name: sugar  UseBy : 03-04-2012
Product name: sugar  UseBy : 08-04-2012

Product list - AFTER sorting by UseBy

Product name: sugar  UseBy : 01-10-2012
Product name: sugar  UseBy : 03-04-2012
Product name: sugar  UseBy : 08-04-2012
Product name: sugar  UseBy : 12-12-2012
Product name: sugar  UseBy : 16-04-2012
Product name: sugar  UseBy : 25-04-2012
Product name: sugar  UseBy : 30-01-2012

Comment: Please post your code, otherwise we'd be guessing what's going on.

Comment: Seems like it would be an issue with the compareTo(date1, date2) method.

Comment: can u provide implementation of compareTo()

Comment: Post the code, not pictures of it.

Comment: Come on now. We're volunteers, so the onus should be on *you* to make it easy for us to help you. We're asking you to post your offending *code* not pictures of it, not a link to the code.

Comment: Rolled back so we can see the code again. Why'd you remove it?

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm only starting to get used to the editor.

Comment: @Frank: You're still playing hide and seek with us, showing bits and pieces of relevant code. Show complete code, like I did in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10771433/839646). I.e., give us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @Frank: again,  you're using the wrong String for your SimpleDateFormatter. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your format String has been copied correctly, your SimpleDateFormat is wrong. It should be `dd-MM-yyyy`, not `dd-mm-yyyy`, since you're interested in **months**, not **minutes**.

You've got:

```
public static Date rtnDate(String dateStr, int currentLineCount)
{
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

When you should be using:

```
public static Date rtnDate(String dateStr, int currentLineCount)
{
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

This would explain everything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm about 90% sure you're comparing `java.lang.String`s and not `java.util.Date`s. Given the date format you mentioned, it'll obviously sort all the days together first. E.g. for a full year, your list would start off:

```
01-01-2012 (1 Jan)
01-02-2012 (1 Feb)
01-03-2012 (1 Mar)
```

Use the Date object to compare on, not a String representation of it.

P.S. a picture is not code. Put your code in your question.

**Update:** Proof that the code you've posted works as expected:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.*;

public class DateComparators {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Product> productList = Arrays.asList(
                new Product(new Date(2012 - 1900, 5, 1)), // 1 Jun 2012
                new Product(new Date(2012 - 1900, 1, 1)), // 1 Feb 2012
                new Product(new Date(2012 - 1900, 2, 15)), // 15 Mar 2012
                new Product(new Date(2012 - 1900, 0, 2)), // 2 Jan 2012
                new Product(new Date(2012 - 1900, 1, 2)), // 2 Feb 2012
                new Product(new Date(2012 - 1900, 0, 1)) // 1 Jan 2012
        );
        Collections.sort(productList, new CustomComparator());
        System.out.println(productList);
    }

    static class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Product> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Product o1, Product o2) {
            return o1.getUseBy().compareTo(o2.getUseBy());
        }
    }

    static class Product {
        private String productName; // sauce pan
        private Date boughtOn; // 4-5-2012
        private Date useBy; // 4-5-2012
        private double boughtAt; // $4.05
        private long quantity; // 9
        private static DateFormat dateFormat;

        Product(Date useBy) {
            this.useBy = useBy;
        }

        public Date getUseBy() {
            return useBy;
        }

        public void setUseBy(Date useBy) {
            this.useBy = useBy;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "\nuseBy=" + useBy;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[
useBy=Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 CST 2012, 
useBy=Mon Jan 02 00:00:00 CST 2012, 
useBy=Wed Feb 01 00:00:00 CST 2012, 
useBy=Thu Feb 02 00:00:00 CST 2012, 
useBy=Thu Mar 15 00:00:00 CDT 2012, 
useBy=Fri Jun 01 00:00:00 CDT 2012]
```

Therefore, you haven't shown us everything. The problem is in something you left out.

Comment: @DavidB: So he claims, yet I stand by my guess. As shown in my update, the code he has shown sorts dates correctly. We're not seeing the code that's producing the described effect.

Comment: No, you actually haven't. You've shown some free-standing code, but nothing that would create the output you've described. You need a main method and a list of products defined before you can start sorting.